# Write Image on Text in PDF Form Fields using ITextSharp

Tags: itext

When I tried to write an image on Text Field, the image is written behind text. It is working for normal text and image but not on Form Fields. I want to write image on Text that covers text behind.

```
void OldMethod()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\";

    string OutLocation = path + "New.pdf";

    string Old = path + "Old.pdf";

    PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(Old);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(OutLocation, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader1, fs))
        {
            int pageCount1 = reader1.NumberOfPages;

            //Create a new layer
            for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount1; i++)
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = reader1.GetPageSize(i);     

                PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(i);

                AcroFields Fields = stamper.AcroFields;

                cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 50);       

                Fields.SetField("Price", @"1323423345");

                Fields.SetFieldProperty("Price", "TEXTCOLOR", BaseColor.RED, null);

                string Img = path + "red_slash.jpg";

                iTextSharp.text.Image jpeg = Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Img), ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                float width = 100;

                float height = 200;

                jpeg.ScaleToFit(width, height); 

                jpeg.SetAbsolutePosition(210, 315);

                cb.AddImage(jpeg);             
            }             
        }
    }
}
```

Here I need to write the image on the field "Price"

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: *When tried to* - please show what you did and in which respect it didn't work.

Comment: The question is indeed unclear. It should at least have a short code sample, because nobody has any idea about the nature of the Text Field. Is it an AcroForm field? In that case, **all** content added to a content stream will be covered by it: annotations *always* cover the content of a page (that's how it's defined in the PDF specification).

Comment: Now that we see the code I agree with @BrunoLowagie, this is 100% trying to put content "in front of" an annotation which just isn't possible. See mkl's answer for some options here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14821049/231316

Comment: Hi Chris Haas.thanks for your answer.it helped me alot